# Getting Invalid length for a Base-64 char array while decrypting cipher text

Tags: c#, encryption, encoding

I'm getting a "Invalid length for a Base-64 char array" while trying to decrypt cipherText password which is encrypted using base64. But at the time of decryption it raises the error message inside the decrypt function. Please help me to overcome this problem. Thanking you in advance.

```
protected void Save(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        //Save into Service Table 

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.CommandText = "insert_user";
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Username", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtUsername.Text.Trim();
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Password", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Encrypt(txtPassword.Text.Trim());
        cmd.Connection = con;
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            lblMsg.Text = "Record inserted successfully";
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }

        finally
        {
            con.Close();
            con.Dispose();
        }
}

protected void Login(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string password;
    string decryptPassword;

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.CommandText = "get_username";
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserName", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtUserName.Text.Trim();
    cmd.Connection = con;

    try
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        rdr.Read();
        password = rdr["Password"].ToString();

    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }

    finally
    {
        con.Close();
        con.Dispose();
    }  
    decryptPassword = Decrypt(password);
  }
```

**Encrypt function:**

```
public string Encrypt(string clearText)
{
    string EncryptionKey = "MAKV2SPBNI99212";
    byte[] clearBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(clearText);
    using (Aes encryptor = Aes.Create())
    {
        Rfc2898DeriveBytes pdb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(EncryptionKey, new byte[] { 0x49, 0x76, 0x61, 0x6e, 0x20, 0x4d, 0x65, 0x64, 0x76, 0x65, 0x64, 0x65, 0x76 });
        encryptor.Key = pdb.GetBytes(32);
        encryptor.IV = pdb.GetBytes(16);
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, encryptor.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                cs.Write(clearBytes, 0, clearBytes.Length);
                cs.Close();
            }
            clearText = Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
        }
    }
    return clearText;
}
```

**Decrypt function:**

```
public string Decrypt(string cipherText)
{
    string EncryptionKey = "MAKV2SPBNI99212";
    byte[] cipherBytes = System.Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText);     //Error: "Invalid length for a Base-64 char array or string."
    using (Aes encryptor = Aes.Create())
    {
        Rfc2898DeriveBytes pdb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(EncryptionKey, new byte[] { 0x49, 0x76, 0x61, 0x6e, 0x20, 0x4d, 0x65, 0x64, 0x76, 0x65, 0x64, 0x65, 0x76 });
        encryptor.Key = pdb.GetBytes(32);
        encryptor.IV = pdb.GetBytes(16);
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, encryptor.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                cs.Write(cipherBytes, 0, cipherBytes.Length);
                cs.Close();
            }
            cipherText = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(ms.ToArray());
        }
    }
    return cipherText;
}
```

Comment: You should be hashing passwords anyway, not encrypting them

Comment: So, the error appears because it's not base64. What is it then? Can you give us an example?